# Can Workflow & Safeguard be combined?

Tags: workflow

I'm looking to add a step in Workflow which validates the Page, ideally using Safeguard.

Obviously a previous step will have to be to publish the Page, as the checks are performed against rendered content.

I am considering a custom automatic Workflow step which communicates with the Active Standards API, to get the results

- Create or Update "asset" - HTML of Page
- Validate "asset" against pre-defined "checkpoint" - minimum acceptable standard

  ```
  Pass - proceed to next step of Workflow
  Fail - return to previous step of Workflow
  ```

However, I am interested if there is anything more "supported" or official in terms of integration?

Comment: In short - workflow isn't really combined - but it can be put on hold whilst you 'do stuff' and then resume when you tell it to. I've not seen anything recommended explicitly for this purpose but we've successfully used the 'suspended' state in workflow for integration with external (to the CMS) services (such as World Server Translation Services) and in all it works quite nicely.

Comment: Interesting, thanks, I'll play around with putting it on-hold.

Comment: If you're using the Safeguard integration in XPM, workflow could have a manual step to "review," as long as that user can see the latest published (minor) changes.

Comment: They have that now. No one does the manual step so needs to be automatic or enforced after the manual step

Comment: @ChrisMorgan - did you ever get a solution to this?

Comment: No out of the box solution, but there is an API that should work from a custom workflow step. Never completed as the work got cancelled.